# importing csv file to mysql choose columns

Tags: php, mysql, csv, csv-import

I import a csv file and write the headline of the csv on the left side. On the right side I create a dropdown. In the dropdownlist I have the values of my mysql columns. I want to select with the dropdowns the appropriate CSV headline.

```
$handle = fopen($dateinameneu, "r");
    $data = fgetcsv ($handle, 500, $spaltentrennzeichen);
    for ($i = 0, $j = count($data); $i < $j; $i++) {
    echo '
     <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="'.$data[$i].'">'.$data[$i].'</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <select id="'.$data[$i].'" name="'.$data[$i].'">
                            <option value="">Choose</option>
                            <option value="email">email</option>
                            <option value="phone">phone</option>                            
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
    ';
```

Now I post it to a new php file. The importfile. There I need to use the variables from the dropdowns. I want to save it to my mysql. But I don't know how to use it.

```
$sql="
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$datei'
    INTO TABLE empfaenger
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$spaltentrennzeichen'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    SET
    email = '###'
mysql_query($sql,$db);
```

Where `###` I need to insert the name of column where I before select in the dropdown that it is the email.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to tell mysql which columns of the table you give in the csv? That is easy using http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/load-data.html, you just give the columns you want to insert in () at the end of the statement. Since you don't give the table structure I have to guess.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$datei'
INTO TABLE empfaenger
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$spaltentrennzeichen'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(empfaenger_name, $value_column_name )
set empfaenger_id = null
;
```

The csv has how many and which columns, the table has which cols? If you give those infos you will get a better answer.

EDIT:
To throw away the non-needed columns you just put them into variables.

(@somecol0, @somecol1, @somecol2, email)

EDIT2:

If the table has columns `empfaenger_id, email, phone`. The csv is given as (empfaenger_id, email) then the statement would be

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$datei'
INTO TABLE empfaenger
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$spaltentrennzeichen'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(empfaenger_id, email ) # that line is variable!
;
```

If you web page says, that the csv is empfaenger_id, phone, the statement is

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$datei'
INTO TABLE empfaenger
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$spaltentrennzeichen'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(empfaenger_id, phone ) # that line is variable!
;
```

You just have to create (after user-submit) a list of the column-names in your SQL-Table for the columns of the csv.

Comment: My csv: 1.line 0;1;2;3;email;phone, 2. line test;test1;test2;test@test.de;012345
My mysql id;email;phone - Thanks for your answer. But 1. I get the dropdown over the for so I don't know the variables...

In your example what is $value_column_name?

Comment: I know my mysql have the filds phone, email and so but I don't know how to say what column it is in the csv. So I want to select what field it is with the dropdowns. But how can I give it to the mysql script?

Comment: Look at the SQL-Table-Structure, there is a sequence of columns. Those columns which are in the csv you have to list in the () - part. Give a simple example table structure and csv line, that makes it more concretely.

Comment: The csv structure is dynamical you can see it on the for - loop. That is at the moment my problem. Because if it were fixed values i have no problem. In my dropdowns the name="x" is the column or headline of the csv. The value is the mysql column. But how I can do it to get these values in the mysql script? Because I need for exampe email = @email, surname = @1 or not? But I do not know how I can take the assignments to the mysql script.

Comment: The assignment is not done via `set email=@email`, but by the sequence inside the (). The table structure is fixed, so give that and three examples for the csv.

Comment: One CSV

1;2;3;4;5;6
test@test.de;Herr;Max;Mustermann;123;1

Second CSV:
1;2;3;4;5;6
Herr;Max;test@test.de;Mustermann;123;1
Third CSV:
title;firstname;email;lastname;phone;number2
Herr;Max;test@test.de;Mustermann;123;1

The mysql is this:
SET
email list = '$ email list'
email = @,
domain = @,
title = @,
first name = @,
last_name = @,
road No = @,
zip = @,
city ​​= @,
phone = @,
status = 'active'

Comment: But how I get this line from my dinamic formular?
(empfaenger_id, email ) # that line is variable!